# How to disable other buttons until the first button is clicked

Tags: android, button

I'm  a newbie in android. I have got four buttons when I click my first tab. I want user to click the first button first rather than randomly clicking other buttons first. so need to disable other buttons until my first button is clicked and once the first button is clicked and when the user returns back all the buttons need to be enabled. How do I do this? Please help!!

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId() == R.id.imgbtn_details)
    {
        attendees_imgbtn.setEnabled(true);
        resources_imgbtn.setEnabled(true);
        contacts_imgbtn.setEnabled(true);
        count = 1;
        Intent detail_intent=new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
        detail_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(detail_intent);
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.imgbtn_attendees && count == 0)
    {

        if(count == 1)
        {
        Intent attendee_intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),AttendeesActivity.class);
        attendee_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(attendee_intent);
        }
        else
        {
            attendees_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
            resources_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
            contacts_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.imgbtn_resources && count == 0)
    {

        if(count == 1)
        {
        Intent resources_intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ResourcesActivity.class);
        resources_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(resources_intent);
        }
        else
        {
            attendees_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
            resources_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
            contacts_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    else if(v.getId() == R.id.imgbtn_contacts && count == 0)
    {

        if(count == 1)
        {
        Intent contact_intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),ContactsActivity.class);
        contact_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(contact_intent);
        }
        else
        {
            attendees_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
            resources_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
            contacts_imgbtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: disable the other buttons by startup of app, on 1st buttons onClickListener() enable them. SO if someone clicks the 1st button then the remaining will enable.

Comment: @ Soumyadip Das, i've tried this.. but after clicking the first, as it returns to the app , all the other buttons would remain disabled as earlier..

Comment: What do you mean by "but after clicking the first, as it returns to the app". Please post your code so that we can understand logic properly

Comment: what happens when 1st button clicked ?? 1> Its clear that it enables other buttons 2> Is this opens another screen ??

Comment: yes Soumyadip Das it opens to another screen after clicking the first button.. I've posted the code also which I've tried..

Comment: place a static boolean class level variable isFirstBtnClikced = false & make it true from on click listener of 1st btn. then from onResume()/onRestart() check this is true or not, if true then enable other buttons.

Comment: @Soumyadip Das:Thanks a lot.. Half my problem is solved now...its working.. but when I navigate to other tabs and come back to this tab containing the buttons.. All buttons remain enabled.. I need those buttons to go back to the same situation if user clicks other tabs..

Comment: Q1: new tab on same activity ?? Q2: Is this always true that whenever u clicks another tab, should it disable all buttons except 1st ?

Comment: Q1: yes Q2: yes exactly Thanks :)

Comment: so add another static var like isAnotherTabSelected = false; and make it true just before switching to the new tab. and from onResume()/onRestart() check if it is true then make buttons disable. Don't forget to make isAnotherTabSelected  = false; from 1st buttons on lick listener. :)

Comment: @Soumyadip Das : how do this " make it true just before switching to the new tab" ? :(

Comment: I don't exactly know/remember what method to use but there should be something listener for tab selection. so implement this on that :)

Comment: k I check and try this.. thanks a lot for the time.. :)

Comment: @ Soumyadip Das : Thanks a lot for the time.. The issue is solved.. :) I'm saved!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `setEnable(true)` for buttons to enable and disable buttons

Answer (score 0):

define a static Boolean variable wasClicked....if but1 was clicked make variable true otherwise false...override this method....as user comes back it will check first than enable or disable as 1st but was clicked or not.

```
    @Override
     protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(!wasClicked){
        but2.setClickable(false);       
        but3.setClickable(false);
        but4.setClickable(false);           
     }else{
        but2.setClickable(true);        
        but3.setClickable(true);
        but4.setClickable(true);            
     }

     }
```

Comment: Clarify "as it returns to the app" app or Activity.... ??? User is closing app or moves to another activity and comes back ?

Comment: the user moves to another activity and comes back.. I've posted the code too.. pls do chk ..

Comment: so in that case use my code....its simple and straight forward....one static variable will do all job u want....when user clicks on first button make wasClicked true and you are done....you wont need to change your code also...

Comment: @ R Gandhi :Thanks for the help.. I'll try this too.. but when I navigate to other tabs and come back to this tab containing the buttons.. All buttons remain enabled.. I need those buttons to go back to the same situation if user clicks other tabs..

Comment: OK i got your idea...Static variable should do your task...Btw...I just show ur Intent flags....U can not use onResume methods with this flags Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP....you have to put your activity in activity stack....otherwise everytime you come back to activity you are creating activity....As design point of view creating same activity everytime is not a good idea...and onResume method will have no sense, too

Comment: k so should I remove those flags?

Comment: yeah....if you want your activity in activity stack....your current flags will destroy activity as soon as user leaves it...and please vote up answer if it helps you :P

Comment: hi the issue is solved now..  Soumyadip Das's tips helped me out.. Thanks a lot for your time R Gandhi.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass variable specifying that you want to enable buttons or not.

First time, pass it as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextAct.class);
intent.putExtra ("ENABLE", "No");
```

When you want to enable the buttons, pass String as Yes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextAct.class);
intent.putExtra ("ENABLE", "YES");
```

Then check in your NextAct class for this string.

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String enableBtn = intent.getStringExtra("ENABLE");
    if (enableBtn != null && enableBtn.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
        button2.setEnabled(true);
        button3.setEnabled(true);
        button4.setEnabled(true);
    } else {
        button2.setEnabled(false);
        button3.setEnabled(false);
        button4.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

So your buttons will be enabled only when you want them to.

Hope that helps.